# What is the Japanese word equivalent for [Remember me] usually found in system login

Tags: translation

I need to translate my web system to japanese languange, and kinda stuck on translating
[remember me] word to its japanese equivalent.

Any suggestion?

Comment: yahoo.co.jp uses ログインしたままにする

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/78).

Comment: I am asking that because the terms used in english website and japanese website is different. It cannot be literally translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most natural translation would be

> ログイン状態を保持する

Cannot remember where I saw it but definitely seen it before.

Comment: this and ログインしたまま is good. Thanks for answering